# (Python) Selenium doesn't get the link when i configure my profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

this is my first question here. i searched a lot in the site to answers, but i don't get it.
Can anyone please help?

i'm trying to open the chrome with my profile, and it opens correctly, but, the line `driver.get("https://google.com")` is not executed

i only could get the link if i remove the parameter 'options=opt'

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myPC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
opt.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

tried to add another parameter, as `services=ser`
tried to use the cookies instead of profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the profile name(Profile 1) in the path as below:

```
opt.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myPC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")
# opt.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

Comment: Well, worked fine to me, when i put the profile within the line above, system automatically have created an new default profile, and every time i run the code, it will lead to the same new default profile.

Really Thank You man <3